# Passing JavaScript array value to Laravel controller without using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

I was trying to send the javascript array value to the controller.
My javascript array output is like that:

```
0 : (4) ['Name', 'contact_email', 'phone number', 'contact_location']
1 : (5) ['John Doe', 'john.doe@example.com', '15551234567', '"New York', ' NY"']
2 : (5) ['Jane Smith', 'jane.smith@example.com', '15552345678', '"Los Angeles', ' CA"']
3 : (5) ['Robert Johnson', 'robert.johnson@example.com', '15553456789', '"Chicago', ' IL"']
4 : (5) ['Emily Davis', 'emily.davis@example.com', '15554567890', '"Houston', ' TX"']
```

Now i have submitted a hidden form to pass the array like that,,

```
<form id="importContact" action="{{url('reviewContacts')}}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" id="contacts" name="data">
</form>
```

on Js Part:

```
$("#contacts").val('');
  $('#contacts').val(dataArray); 
  $("#importContact").submit();
```

But here the problem is when i pass the array through form , it doesn't show output like array.it shows single array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Name,contact_email,phone number,contact_location,John Doe,john.doe@example.com,15551234567,"New York, NY",Jane Smith,jane.smith@example.com,15552345678,"Los Angeles, CA",Robert Johnson,robert.johnson@example.com,15553456789,"Chicago, IL",Emily Davis,emily.davis@example.com,15554567890,"Houston, TX", )
```

How do I get the output as it is like js part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two modifications which you would be needing.

1. You're trying to pass a JavaScript array as a form input value, but form inputs can handle only strings. To fix this use ***[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)***

   ```js
    <input type="hidden" id="contacts" name="data"> // <-- also notice value of name is data now not data[]
    // ...rest of code
    $("#contacts").val('');
    $('#contacts').val(JSON.stringify(dataArray)); // <---- Here
    $("#importContact").submit();
   ```
2. To parse the `JSON` string back into array for your usage, use ***[`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)*** in your controller.

   ```js
   $data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true); // <--- here
   ```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://replit.com/@msankrit/BurdensomeSourPasswords#index.php)***

Comment: this throws error "json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given"

Comment: @Hola working for me. Check the demo once

Comment: @Hola You must use `name="data"` in your HTML form, not `name="data[]"`.